# Java - Simple for loop not producing expected result

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm expecting my code to print a sequence of integers from 0 to 14, but it's not printing out ANYTHING and I have no idea why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userInt;
    int ender = 15;

    for (userInt = 0; userInt>ender; userInt++) {
        System.out.println(userInt);
    }

}
```

Comment: `0` is *never* `> 15`

Comment: Downvoters: can you provide some justification? It's a basic mistake, but a well-written question (OP has provided an attempted solution, expected results, and actual results), so I don't see why this deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: Right-o then this was a dumb question. Thanks for all the help dudes and dudettes.

Answer (score 9):

your for loop will execute WHILE `userInt>ender;` not UNTIL the condition is met.

---

change the `>` to a `<`

```
for (userInt = 0; userInt<ender; userInt++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (userInt = 0; userInt>ender; userInt++) {
```

It's looping *while* `userInt > 15`. Which is never.

You need

```
 for (userInt = 0; userInt  < ender; userInt++) {
```

which will execute the contents of the loop and increment `userInt` until it exceeds 15.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

`userInt>ender` i.e `0 > 15` will return false and hence loop will break within first try

replace this

```
userInt>ender
```

with

```
userInt<ender
```